# CSH /TCSH iterate through all the elements in the variable according to its index

Tags: python, shell, csh, tcsh

I have a three-variable with multiple elements in it.

```
var1   var2 var3
1551    3   7
1662    4   5
1669    6   22
1669    8   23
```

I want to iterate through it according to index and create folder names and enter into that folder if it exists. I wanted to do this in CSH/TCSH

In python, my code will be something like this

```
for i in range(0,len(var1)):
  dir=str(var1)+'_'+str(var2)'_'+str(var3)
  if os.path.exists(dir)== True:
     os.chadir(dir)
  elif
     break
```

But how to implement in CSH/TCSH?

Comment: What are the contents of each of the variables `var1`, `var1` and `var3`? Are they whitespace separted strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to produce the directory names, but I don't know how to "change the directory if it exists " part

```
set i = 0
set len = $#var1
while ($i < = $len)
        echo "$var1[$i]_$var2[$i]_$var3[$i]"
        @ i++
end
```